# Merge columns/rows?

Tags: excel, shell

I have

```
chr12 100 105 'some' 'required' 'data'
chr12 105 120 'some' 'required' 'data'
chr12 120 130 'some' 'required' 'data'
```

I need to make them as

```
chr12 100 130 'some'|'some'|'some' 'required'|'required'|'required' 'data'|'data'|'data'
```

That is, merge overlapping rows and append from all other columns beside the first one. Sorry if I'm sounding vague, however I don't know how to describe this situation.

Looking for a Shell script because then I can quickly process the 20 files that I need to work with.

Comment: Are there always only 2 columns? A more complete example of input/output would be useful. Also good to make an attempt of your own before posting your requirement here.

Comment: There are only two columns. The inputs are actually genomic co-ordinates. They haven't been reported as one continuous region, but are reported as mentioned above (but bigger in number).

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow, please put your previous comment straightly into your question post, and also for better clarification and prevetion getting downwotes, look at [mcve] and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then feel free to edit your post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yours is a horrible question, because it is vague and you got no example or code you've been trying.

That being said, this should do the trick:

```
Sub stackoverflow()

Dim row As Variant
Dim finish As Boolean

    Do
        For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row)

            row = Application.Match(cell.Value, Range("B1:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row), 0)

            If Not IsError(row) Then
                Cells(row, 2).Delete xlShiftUp
                cell.Delete xlShiftUp
                Exit For
            End If

            finish = cell = Range("A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row)

        Next cell
    Loop Until finish = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I agree that the question is not well put and incredibly vague, because I don't know how to describe it well. However, I thank you for trying to provide me with a solution! Is that a python script that you have posted? Might take me some time to get it running. I'll let you know if it works!

Comment: No, its a VBA script. Hit ALT+F11 with your Excel open, create a new module, paste and run.

Comment: The script works when there are only two fields, however now I have another requirement... Kindly check out the edit to my original question, I hope it's clear what I need help with. ALSO I have no idea when it comes to VBA scripting!